# Requirements or conditions to use PHP sessions?

Tags: php, session

I am a bit puzzled on using PHP's session.  Are there any specific requirements or conditions to use sessions?  From all other forums, I can only see that session_start() should be the first line of the php code and nothing else beyond that.

In my test server (with PHP 7.3) it took me a while to get it to work, the only thing I found out is that when I load my site using http, the session doesn't save across load.  And when I load it using https, it works fine.

While at this topic, I am also confuse why this tutorial site: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp doesn't work despite it loaded using https.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-secure

Comment: Do you understand what the SESSION is used for? Do you understand what stateless means in relation to a web site

Comment: Hi, maybe you can help shed some lights?